# Natural Language Processing using nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I need an algorithm to tokenize given sentence into words which are correctly tagged to its grammar meaning.

for example: "People took to the streets and protested"
people-noun
took- adjective
and-conjunction
to- ...and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want part of speech tagging?

```
>>> import nltk
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize("People took to the streets and protested")
>>> nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
[('People', 'NNS'), ('took', 'VBD'), ('to', 'TO'), ('the', 'DT'), ('streets', 'NNS'), ('and', 'CC'), ('protested', 'VBD')]
```

Comment: This uses the standford parser right? i want to do this without the parser.

Comment: No, this uses a POS tagging model inside NLTK.

Comment: Thanks. Can i work more with that command? like i need to store and tag them. @larsmans

Comment: I've no idea what you mean. You have the full Python language at your disposal and the return value of this are standard Python objects.